# Android: Implementing Slideshow

Tags: android, slideshow

I am trying to implement a slideshow in my android app. I have an imageview and a text view in my xml file. I want that imageview to show a slideshow of some images. The images are stored in drawable-hdpi. When I am opening this page, only text view is showing up and not the slideshow. Not a single image is showing.
Following is the java file for the same.

```
package abc.xys;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Wishes extends Activity {

    ImageView slide;
    TextView msg;

    int i=0;
    int imgid[]={R.drawable.friends01,R.drawable.friends02,R.drawable.friends03,R.drawable.friends04,R.drawable.friends05};

    RefreshHandler refreshHandler=new RefreshHandler();

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    class RefreshHandler extends Handler{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Wishes.this.updateUI();
        }
        public void sleep(long delayMillis){
            this.removeMessages(0);
            sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
        }
    };
    public void updateUI(){
        int currentInt=Integer.parseInt((String)msg.getText())+10;
        if(currentInt<=100){
            refreshHandler.sleep(2000);
            msg.setText(String.valueOf(currentInt));
            if(i<imgid.length){
                slide.setImageResource(imgid[i]);

                // slide.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wishes_template);
        slide = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slideshow);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

    }

}
```

The xml file (wishes_template) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/slideshow_layout"
  >

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/slideshow"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:paddingTop="20dp"
              ></ImageView>

    <TextView android:text="10" 
              android:id="@+id/message" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use `android:srcType="centerCrop"` or something else inside your `ImageView`

Comment: One more thing I would to tell is that I had use the same code to implement slideshow and it worked then. But now it's not working.

Comment: And using android:srcType="centerCrop" gives the following error:
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcType' in package 'android'